# How to change sql server tier on Azure VM

Tags: virtual-machine, sql-server, azure

I have Azure VM and I have turned on SQL Server Enterprise and I want to downscale to lower tier, e.g. Standard. Can You tell me where in the config on Azure Portal or on server I can do that?

Thx

Comment: [Change the service tier and performance level (pricing tier) of a SQL database using the Azure portal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-scale-up)

Comment: Am I wrong, or this article is only about separate Azur Databases? Because I found this article earlier, but it won't help me, because I want to lower the tier of the SQL Server installed on Azure Virtual Machine.

Comment: I don't know enough about the difference to comment ob that. Did you check out the Transact SQL/PowerShell method? Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you want to resize your VM to a low-level virtual machine. Am I right?

You could resize your VM on Azure Portal.

[image]